# After downing Laravel web server, could not UP server again by Artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to upload and make some changes on my website, so by calling the below code, I tried to down the laravel server:
**Web.php:**

```
Route::get('/shotdown_website', function () {
    Artisan::call('down');
    return "Website Down successfully";
});
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get up the server again.

```
Route::get('/Turn_Up_Desk2929', function () {
    Artisan::call('up');
    return "Website Up successfully";
});
```

when I write `mywebsite/Turn_Up_Desk2929`  in the browser address bar, it redirects me to the error server page which is 503.

Overall, in the first step, I downed the server but in the second part, I could not up the server again. Additionally, in the PHPstorm terminal, I had not any issues.
Thanks.

Comment: ... because its now down... You need to add [`--secret`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#maintenance-mode) to the down command to add a bypass. You now need to go onto the server via CLI and manually run `php artisan up` in the directory that has the artisan binary

Comment: My host for the website is a sharing host with cpanel, so, I have to ask my host owner to run `PHP artisan up`  in my laravel project.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I can find the answer:

As my website is uploaded on a shared host, so accessing CLI or terminal has been banned, but, there is an easy way for rescuing from the downing website.

1. remove the `down` file in `storage/framework` path
2. then run this function `Artisan::call('up')`

Every thing would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

that's because of server is down and you can not make any request even request that make server up.

so if you want to make server up using request then you need to define a `secret` when making server down and send the secret with up request

the `--secret` can be any string you want:

```
Route::get('/shotdown_website', function () {
    Artisan::call('down',['--secret'=>'630542a-246b']);
    return "Website Down successfully";
});
```

then to access the server as admin you need to send this requet. the secret parameter is token you set in the above code:

```
https://example.com/secret
```

in this way a cookie will be created that determine you are admin and can create any request .

so you can call the below route

```
Route::get('/Turn_Up_Desk2929/', function () {
    Artisan::call('up');
    return "Website Up successfully";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, unfortunately, as previously I downed the server without a secret feature, so the down command with the secret option does not work and redirects the 503 error page.

Comment: so you need access to terminal of server to make your server up. then you can use above code . but if you have cli access you don't need the above code to place your application in maintenane mode .

Comment: Yes, I have to directly run `php artisan up`, unluckily there is not any cli access for executing codes.  appreciate for your help.

Comment: so after hosting provider make up server , you can use the code. I tested it.

Comment: I have new idea . I'll post it

Comment: no , check my new answer

Comment: I will check, please let me a bit time, Thankssss

Answer (score 0):

you can run `Artisan::call('up')` in a provider files like AppServiceProvider.
this file is renderd in any condition even when application is in maintenance mode . then create any request .

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
 public function boot()
    {
        Artisan::call('up');
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I follow this method, but it could not solve it. I  precisely tested it from the app route meanwhile, the android studio and flutter were not able to send requests simply because of laravel server is banned, therefore, the issue is sustained. I believe the sole command which has permission after down is up.